# how to enable session.upload_progress?

Tags: session, php

How to enable `session.upload_progress` ?

Couldn't find `session.upload_progress.enabled` in php.ini in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

This variable is empty

```
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . ini_get("session.upload-progress.name");
echo $key;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has been available for PHP 5.4.0. If its not in your PHP.ini, its likely your using a former version. Otherwise try manually writing it into the php.ini.

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php